# Reflection: Why are there methods like setAccessible()?

Tags: java, reflection, language-design, access-modifiers

Just wondering, why did the people who invented Java write methods like `setAccessible(boolean flag)`, which makes the access-modifiers (specially private) useless and cannot protect fields, methods, and constructors from being reached? Look at the following simple example:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    private double balance = 100.0;

    public boolean withdrawCash(double cash)
    {
        if(cash <= balance)
        {
            balance -= cash;
            System.out.println("You have withdrawn " + cash + " dollars! The new balance is: " + balance);
            return true;
        }
        else System.out.println("Sorry, your balance (" + balance + ") is less than what you have requested (" + cash + ")!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount();
        myAccount.withdrawCash(150);

        Field f = BankAccount.class.getDeclaredFields()[0];
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(myAccount, 1000000); // I am a millionaire now ;)

        myAccount.withdrawCash(500000);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Sorry, your balance (100.0) is less than what you have requested
(150.0)! You have withdrawn 500000.0 dollars! The new balance is: 500000.0
```

Comment: Access modifiers are not an actual security feature, as you can always access any memory within your process memory on current operating systems.

Comment: Because it's often useful. They also provided the ability to prevent this function being used, by running with an appropriate `SecurityManager` configured.

Comment: @Mudu -- that's completely untrue for Java. It's true for C++, but Java code can't access any memory that the runtime doesn't let it. A SecurityManager instance gets to arbitrate whether a particular bit of code can access private methods or not.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill It *is* true for Java as it is for anything else running on a computer, just harder. It is not *allowed* in C++ either, it just so happens that there is no reasonable way to *enforce* this at the level of abstraction C (and by backwards compatible) allows. "Pure" Java with a working sandbox does not provide the tools for this, but in the real world there are nevertheless plenty of options to do it. For starters: You can access the memory from other processes not running Java, or from C code invoked from Java, or by abusing a bug in some part of the JVM.

Comment: @delnan -- yes, of course. But that doesn't mean that access control in Java is not a security feature with respect to Java code -- it absolutely is, and the whole Java security model depends on it. Making a member private, in conjunction with a `SecurityManager` which enforces access control, absolutely prevents any Java code in the JVM from accessing that member. Native code, or code outside the JVM might be able to do it, sure: but the purpose of the security model isn't to prevent the computer user from accessing the memory, it's to prevent untrusted Java code from doing so.

Comment: In C++ it's as a simple preprocessor `define private public`. Access modifiers are not "useless" in C++ either.

Comment: Thank you for making my statement more precise. It is what I wanted to point out, but I over-simplified things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because some code is trusted code -- i.e., if a local application wants to do this, maybe it's not a big deal. For *untrusted code*, though -- i.e., an applet, or a web start application, or RMI stubs, or any other downloaded code -- there's a `SecurityManager` in place, which (generally based on a policy file) has the opportunity to say "Sorry, Charlie" and deny the `setAccessible()` request.

Comment: +1 cool! Are there any tutorials or guidelines to follow for creating a `SecurityManager`?

Comment: Sure. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html) one place to start.

Comment: Note, from Java 2, there's rarely much need to subclass `SecurityManager`. (That is to say, whilst there may be some things you want to with it, configuration is handled through the `ProtectionDomain`/policy mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Well, once you have released a Java program, anyone is free to reverse engineer, or de-compile, it anyways, so if someone wanted it badly enough, they would probably be able to access your your "privates" anyway.

What you *can* do however, is to forbid any foreign code to access your stuff in *your runtime*. That is, if you're for instance using someone else's code you could disable reflections, access to files etc before those libraries are used.

Search for ClassLoader and Security Manager to find out more. [Here](http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/java-ent/security/ch06_02.htm)'s something that looks relevant.